# How do I use JSONARRAY.fromObject?

Tags: json, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using the intellij Gradle project.
To use JSON, I added "implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: 20220320" to the dependencies.

But if I use JSONARRAY.fromObject, I get an error like Can't Resolve method 'fromObject' in JSONARRAY

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

use JSONObject from net.sf.json

fromObject method is not from org.json

use this one

```
implementation 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15'
```

and

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```